# How to set default images folder in flutter sdk

Tags: flutter

The images for my flutter are specified in pubspec.yaml as below. Is there a way to tell dart that images/ is the default folder for images so it doesn't need to be specified? viz AssetImage('background0.jpg') instead of AssetImage('images/background0.jpg')?

assets: 
  - images/ –

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own widget.

```
class MyOwnWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String url;
  MyOwnWidget({this.url});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AssetImage('images/$url');
  }
}

MyOwnWidget('logo.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this worked:

```
String getImageName(url) {
  return ('images/$url');
}


decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage(getImageName('background.png')),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
```